# Stripe charge. Couldn't find Product with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm pretty new in Rails. In my project im using Stripe and I've been trying to make a charge. But every time when I try to run it I got this error. I've spent two days reading and searching, but I dont know what's wrong with it:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ChargesController#create
Couldn't find Product with 'id'=

Extracted source (around line #39):       

    def amount_to_be_charged
      @amount = Product.find(params[:id]).unit_price * 100
    end
```

The code who calls. `app/views/products/index.html.erb`

```
<%= link_to 'Buy', new_charge_path(id: x.id), class:"btn btn-primary"%>
```

My controller `app/controllers/charges_controller.rb`

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :amount_to_be_charged
  before_action :description


  def thanks
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    customer = StripeTool.create_customer(
      email: params[:stripeEmail] ,
      stripe_token: params[:stripeToken]
      )

    charge = StripeTool.create_charge(
      customer_id: customer.id,
      amount: @amount,
      description: @description
      )

    redirect_to thanks_path

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e

    flash[:error] = e.message

    redirect_to new_charge_path

  end


  private

    def amount_to_be_charged
      @amount = Product.find(params[:id]).unit_price * 100
    end

    def description
      @description = Product.find(params[:id]).description
    end


end
```

My routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'thanks', to: 'charges#thanks', as: 'thanks'

  resources :charges, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :sales
  resources :invoices
  resources :products
  resources :categories
  devise_for :users
root 'products#index'
end
```

**Update**

My `new.html.erb`

```
<h1>Charges</h1>
<%= form_tag charges_path do %>
  <article>
    <% if flash[:error].present? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <label class="amount">
      <span>Amount: <%= formated_amount(@amount) %> </span>
    </label>
  </article>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-description="<%= @description %>"
          data-amount="<%= @amount %>"
          data-email="<%= current_user.email %>"
          data-bitcoin="true"
          data-locale="auto"></script>
<% end %>
```

And looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the amount is seated correctly.

My thanks.html.erb

```
<h2>Thank you for your payment!</h2><br>
<p>
Your payment of <strong><%= formated_amount(@amount) %></strong> has been sent.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you specifically passing `id` from the `#new` action to `#create`?

Following this through:

1. You have a link `new_charge_path(id: x.id)`, where `x` is presumably a `Product
2. You hit the `charges#new`, at which point `id` should be in `params`, as expected
3. **Missing piece of the puzzle:** what does your `new.html.erb` look like, and does it set the value of the `id` field to the value of `params[:id]`?

Comment: I updated the question. I Added the new.html.erb and thanks.html.erb

Comment: @Xenetrix: try adding `<%= hidden_field_tag 'id', params[:id] %>` somewhere inside your `new.html.erb` form (i.e. under the `form_tag` block). This should then allow `id` to be passed on to `#create`

Comment: Additionally, once you've proven this works (if it works!) - consider whether it's better to add it as a `data` param on `checkout.js`, so that Stripe will pass it back to you. See the checkout.js docs for more details. This feels a bit more secure, as it'll be much harder for someone to tamper with the `id` e.g. if someone found out your internal IDs, they could pay for a cheap product whilst swapping the ID for a more expensive one...

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `params[:id]` is nil and the `before_action :amount_to_be_charged` runs before each actions and tries to determine the price by fetching a product. Most probably `redirect_to thanks_path` is missing the id param, try this: `redirect_to thanks_path(id: params[:id])`.

A tip: I would recommend to use more descriptive naming here, instead of plain `id` use `product_id`

Answer (score 0):

To debug, look in the logs to see the params hash that is sent to the controller. Also look at your source code to see what x.id equals. Try sending the id in a different format:

```
<%= link_to 'Buy', new_charge_path, id: x.id, class:"btn btn-primary"%>
```

Comment: Ive used Rails.logger.debug( #{@amount.inspect}") and Rails.logger.debug("#{@description.inspect}") in new action method, and they are setted.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the line **redirect_to thanks_path**, what you are trying to do here is redirect to the index action but, you have a before_action filter which will get executed once the redirection happens **amount_to_be_charged** but, the **params** hash is empty because you are not passing any values during the redirection. Please sort this out, if you intend the **amount_to_be_charged** and **description** filter to run only during the **create** then, change the **before_action** as follows,

```
before_filter :amount_to_be_charged, only: [:create]
before_filter :description, only: [:create]
```